# Convertir fecha a integer

Tags: python

Exporté un dataframe de excel a python, pero la columna tiempo se pasó en formato fecha. Quiero pasar ese dato de fecha a un "float" o "integer".

He intentado con "astype()" pero me sale un error.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código que utilicé fue:

```py
df1['Tiempo  '] = df1['Tiempo  '].astype(float)
```

Cuando quiero visualizar el tipo de dato que es la columna me sale lo siguiente

```py
df1['Tiempo  '].dtype
Out[4]: dtype('O')
```

Comment: Por favor pon el codigo o un fragmento de este para poder ayudarte de la mejor forma

Comment: Comparte parte de tu código, o reformula tu pregunta dando más detalle para poder ayudarte

Comment: El código utilizado fue

Comment: df1['Tiempo  '] = df1['Tiempo  '].astype(float)

Comment: has `float(df1['Tiempo'])`

Comment: Lo que dijo mi compa @Christian, dale ese valor a `df1['Tiempo ']` y estas hecho

Comment: Pero al momento de realizar me sale este mensaje "TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>"

Comment: @Irving eso significa que es una serie, lo mas recomendable es que añadas todo el codigo y un ejemplo de tu archivo excel, para ver el dato utiliza `type(df['Tiempo'])`

Comment: prueba `df1['Tiempo '].apply(lambda x: float(x))`

Comment: No amigo, al utilizar el "lambda" me sale el sisguiente erro

Comment: El siguiente error                                                                                                                    float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Timestamp'